# Plot multiple axhlines on the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple control chart on same graph with my feature.
What I have tried so far is:

```
data.plot(y='Feature1',use_index=True).axhline(y=upper_bound,color='red')
data.plot(y='Feature1',use_index=True).axhline(y=lower_bound,color='green')
```

That creates two separate graphs; one with the upper bound and one with the lower bound. How do I plot them on the same graph; essentially, my one plot should have features and upper/lower bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then separate "axhline" as shown below :

```
p = data.plot(y='Feature1',use_index=True)
p.axhline(y=upper_bound,color='red')
p.axhline(y=lower_bound,color='green')
```